# Horizontally Centering jQuery embedded in HTML using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use CSS to center the ASlider Jquery plugin (http://varunnaik.github.io/A-Slider/) which I have embedded into the HTML code for my website. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do it!

It seems adamant that it wants to stay on the left side of my page. I have tried using the float and display CSS elements; neither of them did anything. I even tried using margin and padding, and still nothing happened. Hell, I was desperate enough to see if `text-align: center;` would work but that didn't do anything either.

Here is the script in CSS and HTML to include the ASlider:

```css
.aslider {
  margin: auto;
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="a-slider/aslider.js"></script>

<!--<div id="moveslider">-->
<div class="aslider" data-hide-controls>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="550px" height="300px">
  </div>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="images/pic2.jpg" width="550px" height="300px">
  </div>
</div>
<!--</div>-->
```

Comment: Please post the code. We shouldn't have to leave stackoverflow to answer your question. :)

Comment: What is the div id that the slider is nested in and what styles does it have? We need some code to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float: center;` is not valid so you can remove it from `.aslider`. All you need to do is add a `width` to `.aslider` so that `margin: auto;` takes effect.

```css
.aslider {
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="a-slider/aslider.js"></script>

<!--<div id="moveslider">-->
<div class="aslider" data-hide-controls>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x300" width="550px" height="300px">
  </div>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x300" width="550px" height="300px">
  </div>
</div>
<!--</div>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can do it like this:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
}
.center{
  border: solid red;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    This needs to be centered
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your image width to your .aslide class

```
.aslider{
 margin:0 auto;
 }
 .aslide{
  width:550px;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
```

<---------------------------EDIT--------------------------->

Better yet use this:

```
.aslider{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```